# Reprojected image is rotated, can't match it with DEM

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, image

Why would reprojected sat image be rotated? I can't match it with source DEM map, if there is rotation.

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:31287 input_satmap.tif output_reprojected.tif
```

I use that line in gdal. Source is from SASPlanet, Web Mercator, tried lot of lines,... It won't work. It looks like it won't transform correctly from satelite based Web Mercator to the same projection DEM file is based - Austria Lambert.

In the image it shows how it looks like.

[image: rotated image]

Update 1:

I managed to get it done right, by using qgis. The image was rotated, but in qgis it is easier to match, crop 2 layers than via command line.

Comment: It is normal that image gets rotated when it is reprojected. See the grid north vs true north image in https://www.yukongis.ca/2016/04/12/north-arrows-and-true-north/. You may need to take a bit larger piece of the source imagery so that it covers your DEM after reprojection.